# Динамический select, неправильно выбирается

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle, html, css, javascript

[смотрим здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/vfvtnjd/kDJfk/1/)

**UPD**
Проблема в том,что при hover - е по ячейкам таблицы создается dropdownlist,и когда хочу выбрать из списка, то список скрывается и создается опять же новый список но при пересечений,то есть уже на другом, соседнем ячейке(не знаю как объяснить). Короче можно выбрать из списка только с помощью клавиатуры, кнопки вверх-вниз.
Понимаю что это из за `td:hover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
$('#timetable').delegate('.sel', 'change', function () {
    $(this).parent().html('selected');
}​)​
```

вместо:

```
$('.sel').change(selChange);

function selChange() {
    $(this).parent('td').html('selected');
}
```

Проблема в том, что Вы не подключаете обработчик событий к динамически созданным элементам.

Comment: почему `delegate`, а не `on`?

Comment: можно и `on` просто меняется порядок аргументов,  
     
       $('#timetable').on('change','.sel',function()

Answer (score 1):

Сделал вот так:

```js
var beforeText = '';
var s = 0;
var afterText = '';
$('#timetable td').hover(function() {
  if (s == 1) exit;

  beforeText = $(this).text();
  var sel = '<select class="sel"><option selected disabled>Выбрать</option><option value=9>Чел1</option><option value=6>Чел2</option><option value=8>Чел3</option>    <option value=10>Чел4</option></select>';
  $(this).html(sel).show('slow'); /*показываем список*/
}, function() {
  if (s == 1) exit;
  $(this).find('.sel').hide();
  $(this).html(beforeText);
});

$('#timetable').delegate('.sel', 'change', function() {
  beforeText = 'id=' + $(this).val();
  $(this).parent('td').html(beforeText);
  s = 0;
});
$('#timetable').delegate('.sel', 'click', function() {
  s = 1;
});
```

```css
.calendar-date {
  min-width: 100px;
}
#timetable {
  width: 900px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 1px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: palegoldenrod;
}
#timetable tr.over td,
#timetable tr:hover td {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #BCD4EC;
}
#calendar {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="timetable" rules="all">
  <tr>
    <th>№</th>
    <th>Январь</th>
    <th>Февраль</th>
    <th>Март</th>
    <th>Апрель</th>
    <th>Май</th>
    <th>Июнь</th>
    <th>Июль</th>
    <th>Август</th>
    <th>Сентябрь</th>
    <th>Октябрь</th>
    <th>Ноябрь</th>
    <th>Декабрь</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>1</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>2</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>3</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>4</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>5</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>6</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>7</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>8</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>9</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>10</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>11</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>12</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>13</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>14</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>15</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>16</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>17</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>18</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>19</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>20</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>21</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'>2012-09-21</td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>22</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>23</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'>2012-08-23</td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'>2012-11-23</td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>24</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>25</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>26</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>27</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>28</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>29</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>30</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>31</b>
    </td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
    <td class='calendar-date'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfvtnjd/kDJfk/3/)

Comment: тоже первая мысль была через глобальные флаги, но не нравится мне этот метод, какой то он неуклюжий..

Comment: @FLK,предлагаете сделать через *local variables ?* , или ... ?